# How to implement a collapsible (with a handle) vertical sidebar android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a collapsible sidebar righthand side with a handle. The sidebar contains items which will be dragged and dropped into a linearlayout. Basically the functionality I'm after is sort of like:

Desired Functionality
[image]

Where the "H" is the button/handle which is used to toggle the sidebar open/closed. Also, I would like it to overlay or float over the main content of the activity (such that the expansion and collapse of the view does not impact the layout of the main content).

However I'm struggling to postulate a way of achieving this. I tried to think of it like a navigation drawer, but I won't using this for navigation so I don't think this will be correct. I've been looking into different collapsible views but most of them are horizontal (expands vertically) or are on the same level as the main content and modifies its layout.

Is there any way to create a layout/fragment which allows me to access these drag and drop items from a sidebar like I'm describing? I cannot think of a way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a example in android studio:

Right click on your package -> new -> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity

[image]

Comment: Hi javadaskari, thanks for the response but I am trying to avoid using a navigation drawer (since I will not be using it to navigate).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will work for you

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="H"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/clickBtnId"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Item 1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Item 1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Item 1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#334257"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:itemTextColor="#fff"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**menu/navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <item
        android:title="Item 1"/>
    <item
        android:title="Item 2" />
    <item
        android:title="Item 3" />
    <item
        android:title="Item 4" />
</menu>
```

and Finally **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button clickBtn;
    clickBtn = findViewById(R.id.clickBtnId);
    clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
            if(!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                clickBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            else {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                clickBtn.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

**Output**

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to use Navigation Drawer,

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/black">


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="H"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Explanation

Using Constraint layout, you can enable or disable visibility by a button click. Animation is simply done by **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"**. You can use different views and custom animations as per your requirement.